# Getting all subitems from a list of items with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a dataclass `foo` which has a member `item_li: list[item]`, item is a dataclass which has a member `sub_item_li: list[sub_item]`
I want to return `list[sub_item]` from a method of `foo`. I am primarily looking for a solution with list comprehension.
I got it already working with the following list comprehension which I split into 2 lines:

```
sub_item_li_li: list[list[sub_item]] = [sub_item_li for sub_item_li in [item.sub_item_li for item in self.item_li]] 
all_sub_item_li: list[sub_item] = [sub_item for sublist in sub_item_li_li for sub_item in sublist] 
return all_sub_item_li
```

Is there a way to achieve that without having to create a list of lists first?

Comment: `return [sub_item for item in self.item_li for sub_item in item.sub_item_li]`?

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand list comprehension much better. I tried something similar looking before
`return [sub_item for sub_item in item.sub_item_li for item in self.item_li]`
So its going from outer loops to the inner loops which makes sense of course.
I will be happy to collect more down votes to be reminded of that question of mine forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oli answered the question:

```
return [sub_item for item in self.item_li for sub_item in item.sub_item_li]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Saved my day. I wish I could upvote a few times.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather hard to assist with the exact problem as we don't know how `item` and `sub_item` are implemented. So rather, we can take a more generic approach: treat this as a problem with a list of lists, and we want to flatten out that list using a `list` comprehension.

So something like this should work for that:

```py
# Based on problem statmenet, this is a DOUBLY nested list. So
# list of one item, each item containing a list of another item.
# Let's try to apply that as generically as possible.

aa = [1, 2, 3]
bb = [4, 5, 6]

a = [aa, bb]

# But what are we working with here?
print(a)
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

# flatten out list of lists into one master list
result = [sube for e in a for sube in e]

print(result)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: There is a small difference to your list of lists. Your list items are primitives. Oli's comment made it clear to me.

Comment: Yes, they are primitives, agreed... but the same logic applies to a list of list of dataclass instances

Comment: You have not provided a schema of what `item` and `sub_item` looks like (as mentioned), therefore this is the best possible with the info provided so far

Comment: I should have written instance attributes instead of member but the code snippet makes it clear that the members are attributes. The answer you gave is included in my code snippet because I unnecessarily create a list of lists first on which I apply exactly the pattern you used in your answer. That pattern I found previously also in other posts. None of these posts however helped me understanding how to achieve the same when I have a list of class instances which have a list attribute. `class foo: item_li: list[item]` and `class item: sub_item_li: list[sub_item]`

Comment: alright, I will concede that. I left out accessing the instance attributes on purpose, as it looks like that was already pointed out. I had intended to apply the pattern generically as possible, but I agree the other solution does address this particular case exactly.